# Inconsistent decimal formatting when exporting pandas DataFrame to CSV or XLSX

Tags: python, pandas, csv, decimal

**Background** - I am trying to write a 6000+ row pandas dataframe to an excel file using `df.to_excel`.

**Issue** - Whilst my dataframe writes to a `.xlsx` without issue, despite specifying that the `Entity ID %` and `Account # %` column values should be rounded to 7 decimal places `df = df.round({'Entity ID %': 7, 'Account # %': 7})` I have noticed there are inconsistencies in the decimal places.

**Example** - extract from `.xlsx` output - it's as if numbers are only being rounded to 'significant' decimal places, whereas my code specifies 7-decimal places, regardless of the value. E.g., `0.986` should be `0.9860000` and `1` should be `1.0000000`.

[image]

**Function 1** - this creates the `Entity ID %` and `Account # %` columns, and performs some math, which populates both columns:

```
def ownership_qc():
    df = unpack_response()
    df['Entity ID %'] = '-'
    df['Account # %'] = '-'
    df['Reason to Dismiss'] = '-'
    df['Entity ID %'] = df.groupby('Entity ID')['% Ownership'].transform(sum)
    df['Account # %'] = df.groupby('Entity ID')['% Ownership'].transform(sum)
    return df
```

**Function 2** - this function removes any rows that are `!= 0` or `!= 1` and is supposed to round only values in `Entity ID %` and `Account # %`.

```
def ownership_exceptions():
    df = ownership_qc()
    df = df[(df['Entity ID %'] != 1.0000000) & (df['Entity ID %'] != 0.0000000) & (df['Account # %'] != 1.0000000) & (df['Account # %'] != 0.0000000)]
    df = df.round({'Entity ID %': 7, 'Account # %': 7})
    index = df.index
    number_of_rows = len(index)
    timestr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
    filename = 'ownership_exceptions_'+timestr
    with open(filename, 'w') as output_data:
        df.to_excel(filename+'.xlsx', encoding='utf-8', sheet_name='Ownership Exception Report')
    print("---------------------------\n","EXCEPTION REPORT:", number_of_rows, "rows", "\n---------------------------")
    return df
ownership_exceptions()
```

**Useful info** -

1. I am performing the 7-decimal place rounding on the dataframe, and not when writing to a `.xlsx`. Could this be the issue?
2. I have tried writing to a `.csv` as well as removing the `utf-8` encoding, without any luck.

Is anyone able to help guide me as to why there are inconsistencies in the decimal rounding, as demonstrated in the example screenshot, from the `.xlsx` file?

Comment: I might be totally off, but isn't this - _`0.986` should be `0.9860000` and `1` should be `1.0000000`_  - just the way Excel **displays** numbers by default, and has nothing to do with the data modifiying pandas part? If you want to change that, you have to adjust the format of the cells.

Comment: You are correct, however I am looking to standardize all values to 7-decimal places, regardless of whether 'significant' or not.